# I am getting an error saying "Overflow" in MS Access query when I try to use CDate

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT DISTINCT IWTUSER_ALARMS.NAME, IWTUSER_ALARMS.AID, IWTUSER_ALARMS.DUR, 
   Int(CInt([DUR])/86400) AS DAYS, Int((CInt([DUR]) Mod 86400)/3600) AS HOURS, 
   Int(((CInt([DUR]) Mod 86400) Mod 3600)/360) AS MINUTES, 
   Int((((CInt([DUR]) Mod 86400) Mod 3600) Mod 360)/60) AS SECONDS
FROM IWTUSER_ALARMS
   WHERE (((CDate(Format([IWTUSER_ALARMS].[ITIME],"0000-00-00 00\:00\:00 ")))>=Date()-10))
GROUP BY IWTUSER_ALARMS.NAME, IWTUSER_ALARMS.AID, IWTUSER_ALARMS.DUR, 
   CInt([DUR])/86400, CInt([DUR]) Mod 86400, (CInt([DUR]) Mod 86400) Mod 3600, 
   ((CInt([DUR]) Mod 86400) Mod 3600) Mod 360
ORDER BY IWTUSER_ALARMS.DUR DESC;
```

Comment: What would Date()-10 even logically do?

Answer (score 0):

After so many trial and error and gathering several information from different sources I was able to solve this problem - Here is the working code below.

```
SELECT T.ID, T.NAME, ACOUNT AS AlarmCOUNT
```

FROM (

SELECT   DISTINCT(IWTUSER_ALARMS.NAME) AS NAME, COUNT(IWTUSER_ALARMS.NAME) AS ACOUNT, IWTUSER_ALARMS.AID AS ID

```
FROM IWTUSER_ALARMS

WHERE (((CDate(Format([IWTUSER_ALARMS].[ITIME],"0000-00-00 00\:00\:00 ")))>=Date()-1))
```

GROUP BY IWTUSER_ALARMS.NAME, IWTUSER_ALARMS.AID

)  AS T
ORDER BY T.NAME DESC;